# Collapsing Google Adsense Divs

Tags: adsense

I have read a number of discussions on this, however most are related to using Google Publisher Tags and not responsive ads.

I have set responsive ads from within Adsense to "Collapse this adunit, otherwise show a blank space"

The problem is that my first ad unit on the page always shows a blank 280x300 blank space on mobile devices.

All of the other adspaces collapse as expected. I tried to remove the top advertisement (above the fold). When I do this, the 2nd ad unit (which is now the 1st) is showing a large 280x300 blank space.

It will initially be collapsed on load, then quickly expands to show a blank space.

I have tested this on both samsung browser and chrome mobile browser. This is creating a problem as I now have a large blank space above the fold. I have also set my adsense display balance to 60% so a blank adspace happens frequently.

I am using the following code (fairly standard adsense code)

```
<div class="bottommargin-sm">
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
        style="display:block;"
        data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxx"
        data-ad-slot="xxxx"
        data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
        <script>
            (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
        </script>       
</div>'
```

The only solution I have seen is this https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/3072674?hl=en however this is not for responsive ads that I have setup

Other things I have tried include: loading a dummy ad unit first with display set to none, disabling async, changing parent div to row/container-fluid. Disabling Addthis/OneSignal plugins, disabling cloudflare rocketloader, adding 100%/auto width/height, adding overflow:hidden to parent div. Surround the window.adsbygoogle code with window.onload = function(){.

Another option I thought I could try would be to migrate to DoubleClick and I assume they would have away to manage this situation?

Comment: I have the same issue. It's sad there isn't any solution yet. BTW I have observed that ads that display above the fold don't collapse. It has nothing to do with being the first ad unit. If you let your site fully load in a new tab before switching to that tab, all empty ads will collapse (I use Chrome). Also if you jump to bottom of the page before the ads load, the ads there won't collapse. I hope they fix it coz empty space is bad for site design.

Comment: I have not yet had a the time to test it out, but setting it up via google ad manager instead of directly through adsense is a possible solution https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/3072674?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this problem had been annoying me for so long. Google now has a solution. You can add the following CSS to your stylesheet

```
ins.adsbygoogle[data-ad-status="unfilled"] {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Reference: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/10762946?hl=en